# MYSQL - Duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Hi I am currently writing some software for work to manage our stock.
I searching through 2 tables

master_stock (Holds every single stockCode and description)
stock (Holds stockCode, location, quantity ...)

Everything is fine but this is my problem im having.

Just say my stock table has 2 records with the stockCode as "testcode" but both have different locations and quantitys

Then I have my master_stock with 1 instance of that stockCode and its description

If i search for say "testcode" then ill get 3 results 2 coming from stock which is good, but i'll also get the one that comes from master_stock I want to have it so if there is at least one result in stock then I  don't want to show the row from master_stock, but if nothing is found in stock then show the one from master_stock.

So whats happening is I'm returning results i don't need to see which means its slower to search and it will be confusing for employees to look at due to the amount of results

```
SELECT ms.stockCode AS 'Stock Code',
        ms.description AS 'Description',
        st.quantity AS 'Quantity',
        um.UnitMeasurementName AS 'Unit Measurement',
        dep.departmentName AS 'Location',
        st .rack AS 'Rack',
        st.cost AS 'Cost Per Unit',
        (st.cost * st.quantity) AS 'Total Cost',
        sc.conditionDescription AS 'Condition'

FROM stock As st

INNER JOIN master_stock ms on ms.stockCode = st.stockCode
INNER JOIN racks r on r.rack= st.rack
INNER JOIN departments dep on dep.departmentId = r.departmentId
INNER JOIN unit_measurements um on um.unitMeasurementId = ms.unitMeasurementId
INNER JOIN stock_conditions sc on sc.conditionId = st.stockCondition

WHERE ms.stockCode LIKE '%testcode%'

Union DISTINCT

SELECT  ms.stockCode AS 'Stock Code',
        ms.description AS 'Description',
        '0',
        'NO MEASUREMENT',
        'NO LOCATION',
        'NO RACK',
        '0',
        '0',
        'NO CONDITION'

FROM master_stock As ms

WHERE ms.stockCode LIKE '%testcode%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to drop the union altogether and use a LEFT JOIN from master_stock instead of INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT ms.stockCode AS 'Stock Code', 
    ms.description AS 'Description', 
    IFNULL(st.quantity, 0) AS 'Quantity', 
    ...
FROM master_stock as ms
LEFT JOIN stock as st on ms.stockCode = st.stockCode
WHERE ms.stockCode LIKE '%testcode%
```

This should give you all master-stock entries that match with NULL values where there is no corresponding stock entry.  You can then replace the NULL values with your constant 'NO MEASUREMENT' string in your display routine, or use IFNULL expressions in the SELECT to return 'NO MEASUREMENT' where the stock values are NULL.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly, exactly how I wanted it to work! cant believe it was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join the 2nd query of the union on stock table to determine if there is an entry in the stock table with the same code:

```
...
union distinct
SELECT  ms.stockCode AS 'Stock Code', 
        ms.description AS 'Description', 
        '0', 
        'NO MEASUREMENT', 
        'NO LOCATION', 
        'NO RACK', 
        '0', 
        '0', 
        'NO CONDITION'
FROM 
        master_stock as ms
        LEFT JOIN stock as st on ms.stockCode = st.stockCode
WHERE ms.stockCode LIKE '%testcode%' and st.stockCode IS NULL;
```